# How to show textarea with html format in php page

Tags: php, html, richtextbox

How to show plain text which is inside of following php as html rich text?

```
<?php echo $text_description; ?>
```

for example:

the html code inside of above code is:

```
    <b><font color="#0066FF">English </font><br><font color="#FF00FF"><br></font><br><br><font color="#6666FF">Account Number: 1234567890 Account Holder </font><br><br><font color="#990000">Name:  Swift Code: <img src="logo.png"></font></b>
```

But in front page . it's showing as plain text, not rich text, how to solve it?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's inside `$text_description`?

Comment: It's html format, something like this  <b><font color="#0066FF">English Bank Transfer via </font><br><font color="#FF00FF"><br> Instructions
</font><br><br><font color="#6666FF">Account Number: 1234567890
Account Holder </font><br><br><font color="#990000">Name: 
Swift Code: &nbsp;
</font></b>

Comment: But your questions isn't clear. Where `<?php echo $text_description; ?>` is being called, inside which code and what the first code block has to do with the rest?

Comment: I updated the question, now I think so it's clear ...

Comment: Only one more thing: can you show the snippet of PHP code where the script/function assings that HTML string to the variable `$text_description`?

Answer (score 0):

consider using `htmlspecialchars($str);` where `$str` is your string.

Comment: Like this, I've to update all pages, what is simple way to convert everything inside of code as html format?

Comment: I answered till best of my knowlegde or else you can wait till other get you on board.

Comment: Thanks buddy lets see